# How to get certain key value pairs from an array of object

Tags: javascript, vue.js

```
records = [{id: 231, first_name: "Jack", last_name: "Aston", email: "jack55@xyz.com"}, {id: 232, first_name: "Roy", last_name: "Dillon", email: "roy@xy.com"}, {id: 233, first_name: "Jacy", last_name: "Wilson", email: "jacy@x.com"}]

fields = ['id', 'email', 'last_name']
```

How can I fetch only 'id', 'email', and 'last_name' from records just so that data looks as below in javascript?

```
new_records = [{id: 231, email: "jack55@xyz.com", last_name: "Aston"}, {id: 232, email: "roy@xy.com", last_name: "Dillon"}, {id: 233, email: "jacy@x.com", last_name: "Wilson"}]
```

Comment: here is a handy function you can use https://github.com/30-seconds/30-seconds-of-code/blob/master/snippets/pick.md . map the records array and use this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const records = [{id: 231, first_name: "Jack", last_name: "Aston", email: "jack55@xyz.com"}, {id: 232, first_name: "Roy", last_name: "Dillon", email: "roy@xy.com"}, {id: 233, first_name: "Jacy", last_name: "Wilson", email: "jacy@x.com"}]

const fields = ['id', 'email', 'last_name']

console.log(records.map(i=>Object.fromEntries(fields.map(f=>[f, i[f]]))))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const newRecords=records.map(item=>{return {id,email,last_name}})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Object.prototype.entries` to change the object's key/value pairs into an array that contains the key and value.

```
 Object.entries({ id: 231, first_name: "Jack" });

 // [[id, 231], ["first_name", "Jack"]];
```

You can then use that to filter the key's value and return only these fields that you need. Then you can use `Object.prototype.fromEntries` to reverse the process and construct an object from key/value arrays.

Here's a quick example:

```js
const records = [{id: 231, first_name: "Jack", last_name: "Aston", email: "jack55@xyz.com"}, {id: 232, first_name: "Roy", last_name: "Dillon", email: "roy@xy.com"}, {id: 233, first_name: "Jacy", last_name: "Wilson", email: "jacy@x.com"}]

const fields = ['id', 'email', 'last_name']

const newRecords = records.map((record) => Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(record).filter(([key, value]) => fields.includes(key) ? [key, value] : null))
);

console.log(newRecords);
```